# How would this query be evaluated (nested)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE edw.dbo.load_control 
SET ROW_COUNT=?, end_time=getdate() 
WHERE package_name=? 
 AND load_control_id=(
    SELECT MAX(load_control_id) 
    FROM edw.dbo.load_control
 )
```

I'm more concerned about the WHERE clause. Would it just select the max id and return that or would it evaluate the max id with the and package_name.

So for example if the max(id) was 6 but package_names were different and the next max(id) is 5 and the package names are the same it would update id 5 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specifications in your where clause are not conditional, sql server interprets exactly what you tell it. Everything not equal to your package_name would be filtered out. Then, everything that has a load_control_id not equal to the max would also be filtered out. Sql server has no problem with returning an empty set.

if you want the max load_control_id for the specified package_name, that is a condition that you can add in your subselect.

```
(select max(load_control_id)
from edw.dbo.load_control
Where package_name = ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `UPDATE` statement will update a row that

- has a `package_name` that matches the parameter passed in
- has `load_control_id` equal to the `max(id)` **without** taking into account that `package_name` (after all, there's **no condition** for `package_name` in that subquery!)

Since in your case, there is no row with the given `package_name` and the value of 6 - no row will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are saying

```
select max(load_control_id) from edw.dbo.load_control
```

will return 6.

Then the update will be read as

```
update edw.dbo.load_control 
set ROW_COUNT=?, end_time=getdate() 
where package_name=? and load_control_id=6
```